# PHP + Jquery + JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Tenho `function` que chama um ajax. Como segue abaixo:

```
    function verifica(){ 
      var meuid = $('.meuid').attr('id');   
      var datas = "user="+meuid;        
      $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: 'sys/stream2.php',                                  
             data: datas                
          }).done(function( data ) {                                         
            //alert(data);
            $('#nome').html(data);                
          });
    }
```

E no stream, tenho um select para isso junto com um `foreach` como segue:

```
foreach ($gUsuarios as $usuarios) {
        $agora = $usuarios['AGORA'];   
        if ($agora >= $usuarios['cUsu_Limite']) {            
            echo json_encode(array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'],
                                   'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-red'));            
        }else{    
            echo json_encode(array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'],
                                       'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-green'));
        }
```

e o retorno, me apresenta assim:

```
{"usuarioon":"1","status":"fa fa-circle-o text-red"}
{"usuarioon":"3","status":"fa fa-circle-o text-red"}
```

Isso quer dizer que ele me retorna corretamente, mas o problema é: como dividir isso individualmente? Já tentei com `ParseJson`, mas não deu certo, creio que seja porque estou retornando um `array`, dentro de um `foreach`.
O que quero na verdade, é:

no elemento  ele mude a classe para: 'fa fa-circle-o text-green', mas pra isso preciso saber que usuário, então trago o código do usuário atrelado. Preciso setar assim:

> $('#'+data.usuarioon).addClass(data.status);

Alguém já passou por isso, podem me ajudar ??

Comment: Acho que o título da pergunta deveria ser mais específico, não?

Comment: E como acha que deveria ser o título @WallaceMaxters ?? Ao que vejo o título seria simplesmente para identificar o meu problema, por isso existe o conteúdo... Algo que possa acrescentar para sanar minha dúvida ?

Comment: Está certo que o conteúdo está na pergunta, então é por isso que você precisa de um bom título. Pois outras pessoas que passarem pelo seu problema poderão pesquisar e achar.

Comment: Bruno apenas como sugestão, o titulo deve resumir o problema de forma mais curta possivel, assim quem veja sua pergunta, já entra sabendo do problema, e vai ler sua descrição para mais detalhes de como te ajuda a resolver. Não leve para o pessoal, a sugestão do @WallaceMaxters foi para te ajudar a melhorar a visibilidade da pergunta no site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema é o mesmo do [jquery ui autocomplete + php não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120163/jquery-ui-autocomplete-php-n%c3%a3o-funciona/120195#120195)

Você está a gerar mais de um JSON.

### Mude o PHP:

Troque isto:

```
foreach ($gUsuarios as $usuarios) {
        $agora = $usuarios['AGORA'];   
        if ($agora >= $usuarios['cUsu_Limite']) {            
            echo json_encode(array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'],
                                   'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-red'));            
        }else{    
            echo json_encode(array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'],
                                       'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-green'));
        }
}
```

Por isso:

```
$jsonAux = array(); 
// Algumas versões do PHP (acho que < PHP 7) exibem no erro se não houver isso!

foreach ($gUsuarios as $usuarios) {
        $agora = $usuarios['AGORA'];   
        if ($agora >= $usuarios['cUsu_Limite']) {            
            $jsonAux[] = array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'],
                                   'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-red');            
        }else{    
            $jsonAux[] = array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'],
                                       'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-green');
        }
}

echo json_encode($jsonAux);
```

**Resultado:**

```
[{"usuarioon":"1","status":"fa fa-circle-o text-red"},{"usuarioon":"3","status":"fa fa-circle-o text-red"}]
```

### Enquanto isso no JQuery:

Você precisa criar um loop para executar a cada array definida acima, assim irá executar a cada vez.

```
function verifica(){ 
  var meuid = $('.meuid').attr('id');   
  var datas = "user="+meuid;        
  $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: 'sys/stream2.php',                                  
         data: datas                
      }).done(function( data ) {                                         

         // Cria um loop para cada array do data:
         $.each(data, function(a) {
            $('#'+this.usuarioon).addClass(this.status);         
         }


      });
}
```

### Teste-me:

Por motivos de visualização o `addClass` foi alterado para `text`!

```js
var data = [{
  "usuarioon": "1",
  "status": "fa fa-circle-o text-red"
}, {
  "usuarioon": "3",
  "status": "fa fa-circle-o text-red"
}];


$(':button').click(function() {

  $.each(data, function(a) {
    $('#' + this.usuarioon).text(this.status);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<x id='0'>Meu é ID 0</x>
<br>
<x id='1'>Meu é ID 1</x>
<br>
<x id='2'>Meu é ID 2</x>
<br>
<x id='3'>Meu é ID 3</x>
<br>
<x id='4'>Meu é ID 4</x>
<br>

<button>SIMULAR AJAX</button>
```