# jquery ui autocomplete + php não funciona

Tags: php, jquery-ui, autocompletar

Tenho os seguintes códigos que não estão funcionando:
Talvez eu deva acrescentar algo neles, mas não sei como...
JS:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#busca').autocomplete(
    {
      source: "busca_empresa.php",
      minLength: 1
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```html
<label for="busca">
 <span>Pesquisa:</span>
 <input type="text" id="busca"/>
</label>
```

PHP

```html
<?
include('conecta.php');

$pesquisa = $_GET['term']; 
$sql = "SELECT * from anuncios where nome_emp like '%$pesquisa%'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

while ($ln = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
 echo json_encode($ln['nome_emp']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema ocorre porque você está gerando sempre um novo JSON.

Você deve criar uma ARRAY de json, para isso pode usar:

```
<?php
//...

$json = array(); 
// Cria uma array (para remover erro em algumas versões do PHP)

while ($ln = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $json[] = $ln['nome_emp']; 
    // Adiciona um valor a cada "while" dentro da array.
}

echo json_encode($json);
// Exibe toda a array ($json) em JSON.

//..
?>
```

**Comparação:**

*SEU CODIGO:*

Suponha que existe esse código, usando sua função, da pergunta:

```
$dbs = array('biscoito', 'bolacha', 'cogumelo');
// Simulação de um "banco de dados

foreach($dbs as $db){
// Mesmo que um while

echo json_encode($db);
}
```

Resultado:

```
"biscoito""bolacha""cogumelo"
```

*MEU CODIGO:*

Suponha que utilize o meu código:

```
$dbs = array('biscoito', 'bolacha', 'cogumelo');
// Simulação de um "banco de dados

$json = array();
// Cria uma array (para remover erro em algumas versões do PHP)

foreach($dbs as $db){
// Mesmo que um while

$json[] = $db;
}

echo json_encode($json);
// Exibe toda a array ($json) em JSON.
```

Resultado:

```
["biscoito","bolacha","cogumelo"]
```